# put html in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that in the input field for a user there is predefined (in the "Einkommen" field) text (see picture)[image].

How can I do this?

Here is my code for the other fields:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function sumValues() {

        var num1;
        var num3;
        var num4;

        num1 = Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
        num3 = ((num1 * 0.12) - (num1 * 0.118)) / 12;
        num4 = ((num1 * 0.12) - (num1 * 0.118)) * 15500;

        document.formcalc.txtres.value = 'Fr. ' + Math.round(num3) + '.-';
        document.formcalc.txtres2.value = 'Fr. ' + Math.round(num4) + '.-';
        // document.getElementById("result").value = res;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. Could you please provide more information?

Comment: When you want to change color of the input?

Comment: So is what you want for the input field to already have "Fr." inside before a user puts a number in? I can't really understand...

Comment: Please post your html code. Do you want it to be there when the page loads? In that case just use the the `value=""` tag. Or if it should be a hint you can use the `placeholder=""` tag.

Comment: @DimitrisDamilos Yes, exactly! sry for missunderstanding

Comment: @zenubeh I have added a solution for you below. Please mark it with the right answer if it was what you're looking for.

Comment: @zenubeh you want the `Fr.` to be already present in `input` or want to add it after user add something?

Comment: need to be already in input

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you're asking. 
But in HTML with JavaScript, what you have commented:

```
document.getElementById("result").value = "90000";
```

is actually correct if your intention is to set a value over the input.

Also, I'm wondering if by "predefined" you mean actual text or just a placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

this is my code:

```
<div class="container content-center" id="margin">
    <form name="formcalc">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Einkommen</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <!-- <div class="input-group-addon">Fr.</div> -->
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtnum1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <fieldset disabled>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dein Ersparniss / Jahr</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Verlust Stadt Wil / Jahr</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres2" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Berechnen" onClick="sumValues()">
    </form>
    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <section class="container">
        <p class="lead" id="lead"> Ist es dir Wert, dass deine Stadt pro Jahr XXX weniger Budget zur Verfügung hat
            und du XXX mehr pro Jahr in der Tasche hast?
        </p>

    </section>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">
    <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">created by Behar Zenuni</small>

</div>
```

I want for the input field to already have "Fr." inside before a user puts a number in.

Comment: for this label:

<label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dein Ersparniss / Jahr</label>

Comment: you don't have to put your code in answer. just `edit` your original question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you want to add the "Fr." prefix and ".-" suffix to your value automatically, right? One way to do this is using the [onBlur event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp), so when the user clicks / navigates out of the field, the code will add the rest.

An example, would be with your HTML being:

`<input name="einkommen" type="text" value="" onblur="formatValue(this)">`

and add this function to your Javascript:

ES5:

```
function formatValue(e) {
    e.value = 'Fr. ' + e.value + '.-';
};
```

ES6:

```
const formatValue = e => e.value = `Fr. ${e.value}.-`;
```

Comment: If a user can input data more than once it would be better to replace `Fr.` in `val()` first.

Comment: @KHansen correct! So, if this is what they need, they could add something like `e.value = e.value.replace('Fr. ', '').replace('.-', '');` before the update, or something even better which extracts the value first.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  sumValues = function() {
    var num1;
    var num3;
    var num4;
    num1 = 90000;
    num3 = ((num1 * 0.12) - (num1 * 0.118)) / 12;
    num4 = ((num1 * 0.12) - (num1 * 0.118)) * 15500;
    $('input[name="txtnum1"]').val(num1);
    $('input[name="txtres1"]').val('Fr. ' + Math.round(num3) + '.-');
    $('input[name="txtres2"]').val('Fr. ' + Math.round(num4) + '.-');
    $('input[name="txtnum1"]').addClass( "colored-background" );
  };
})
```

```css
.colored-background {
  background: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Einkommen</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtnum1" value="Fr.  .-" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dein Ersparniss / Jahr</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres1" value="Fr.  .-" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dein Ersparniss / Jahr</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres2" value="Fr.  .-" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Berechnen" onClick="sumValues()">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for! thank you!!
Can you also show me how to "Fr. .-" also for the first input field?

Comment: @zenubeh Replace current code for first *input field* with this: `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtnum1" value="Fr.  .-" readonly>`. This part -> `value="Fr.  .-"` is responsible for putting **"Fr.  .-"** *value* to *input field*. BTW if this solution works for you than you can make it the accepted answer so that it will be helpful for others to find the answer.

Comment: But if I want to put my own owner than it doesn't work. On your code the first input is predefined as "9000". What if I want to put any number

Comment: @zenubeh In JavaScript code `num1 = 90000;` is setting the value of first input, If you want to change the value of first input change `num1` in JavaScript.